# Problems with responsive design and coding

Tags: html, css

I have problems to get any response when coding Responsive design and I don't understand why. Is it my phone that is the problem or the code:

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  menu {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
<style>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a><img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Start">car</a></li>
    <li><a><img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Start">bike</a></li>
    <li><a><img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Start">train</a></li>
    <li><a><img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Start">truck</a></li>
</ul>
```

This do not fit my display on the phone, vertically. Is it something worng with the code?

Comment: Well you're missing a `#` in your CSS selector -- it should be `#menu`.

Answer (score 2):

In your CSS you use `menu`, which selects elements whose tag name is `menu`. If you wanted to select your menu, you should use `#menu` instead, which will select the element with an `id` of `menu`, like this :

```html
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 380px) {
  #menu {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
<style>

<ul id="menu">
    <li><a><img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Start">car</a></li>
    <li><a><img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Start">bike</a></li>
    <li><a><img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Start">train</a></li>
    <li><a><img src="./img/logo.jpg" alt="Start">truck</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the responsive meta tag in HTML markup or not? Here it is

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Yes it is added bit still no response on my code.  Try this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/md7dani/b2Lx3skz/5/